# Python regular expression searching for a number

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex, but looking through a string to find whether or not a pattern exists.

I've tried using the following python code:

```
prog=re.compile('555.555.555')
m=prog.match(somestring)
if m: print somestring
```

I'm trying to find 3 groups of 5's separated by any number. This code doesn't return what I'm looking for though.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here's some code to test a more basic version:

```
i,found=0,0
while found==0:
    istr=str(i)
    prog=re.compile(r'1\d2\d3')
    m=prog.search(istr)
    if m:
        print i
        found=1
        break
    i=i+1
```

This returns 1312 rather than 10203

Comment: You probably want '555\d+555\d+555'? Please clarify with example.

Comment: What's an example ``somestring``?

Comment: I guess that you want also to use ``prog.search`` not ``prog.match``

Comment: Example somestring: 12345552152

Comment: Small aside: I'd recommend you to read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For example, you should surround the assignment operator `=` with spaces (unless used for keyword arguments).

Comment: Also, your example string only contains one run of `555`s - your regex is looking for three of them. And by "number", do you really mean "number" or "digit"?

Comment: Yes, I want to find 3 separate runs of 5's, or other combinations, but with any digit in between

Comment: So your example string should *not* match? Please add some examples (by editing your question) of strings you do/don't want to match.

Comment: I ran your code, it returns `10203` as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is OK (sort of), but you're using it wrong. You need

```
m = prog.search(somestring)
```

or the regex will [only find a match if it is at the beginning of the string](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match).

Also, if you really only want to allow a single digit between each group of `555`s, use

```
prog = re.compile(r'555\d555\d555')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Tim - see additional information in the description